# How to sort by a formule in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

I have a field named `count` and it has values like
`10-3` , now I want to sort by finding `3/10` in all rows and sort by that .
Is it possible in mysql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should fix your data structure.  Storing two different values in a field is simply bad relational database design.  Storing character strings as numbers is also bad design.

Sometimes, though, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  In MySQL, this is pretty easy in your case:

```
order by (substring_index(count, '-', -1) + 0) / nullif(substring_index(count, '-', 1) + 0, 0)
```

It basically splits the string apart and does the arithmetic.

Comment: I think it is okay to add 2 variable in one field and use data-mining , and edit one field to do 2 work

Comment: @Mehdi . . . It is bad relational database design.